# funcion python con django

Tags: javascript, python, django

Buenos dias,
Estoy empezando a usar Django y bueno tengo un problema, y es que no soy capaz de llamar a una funcion que he creado en python a traves de un boton y/o un href.

En mi fichero views.py tengo el metodo que quiero ejecutar cuando haga click en el enlace o en el boton(intente realizarlo de las dos maneras y ninguna me funciona -.-').

```
@userRegistered
def getSyncGit(request, section):
       print 'PATATA' #(lo tengo para ver en el log si se ejecuta o no.)
       path = os.environ.get('BASE_DIR') + '/DEAdministration/admSyncGit/'
       cmd =  '. ' + path + 'p.sh '
       p = sp.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', cmd], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
       result = p.wait()
       return HttpResponseRedirect(getURL(request.LANGUAGE_CODE, '/assistant/configuration/project/list/'))
```

Luego en el fichero de urls.py importo dicho metodo y creo la url de la siguiente manera:

```
from .views import getSyncGit

url(r'^/project/sync/$', getSyncGit, {'section':'configuracion'}, name='pgetSyncGit'),
```

y luego en el .html tengo lo siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendSyncProject()
        {
        $.ajax({url: "{% url 'pgetSyncGit' %}", success: function(result){
            alert('bien');
            }});
        }
</script>
<td>
    <input id="butSendSyncProject" type="button" name="butSendSyncProject" style="margin-left:1px;" value="{% trans 'Sincronizar proyectos' %}" onclick="sendSyncProject()" />
</td>
<td>
    <a href = "{% url 'pgetSyncGit' %}"> asdasdasdasdasddas </a>
</td>
```

Cuando hago la llamada por el botón , me sale el mensaje de alert, pero no se ejecuta la función, ya que no printea el 'PATATA'

Cuando hago la llamada a través del href, me redirecciona a la pagina "/project/sync/" con un error , pero tampoco realiza correctamente el método por que no hace el print ni nada....

Alguna ayuda?

Muchas gracias.

--- EDITO ---
A la hora de ejecutarlo, tengo abierto el log del servidor, entonces los print si que me aparecen en el logger.

Lo raro es que ... Si el metodo que he creado , lo meto en alguno ya existente, si hace la llamada correctamente y me hace el print por el log del servidor.

Sin embargo, cuando lo hago de la manera que estoy haciendolo, llamando el url.py una direccion con el metodo y pasandole el href a esa direccion, me da el siguiente error :

```
"Failed to delete table with cod_project sync. -- invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'sync'"
```

--EDIT2--SOLUCIONADO.

Unicamente he cambiado el orden el url.py ... y funciona :S

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, el funcionamiento que describes parece normal, cuando ejecutas tu servidor de desarrollo con el comando `python manage.py runserver` solo estas ejecutando el servidor, y no vas a ver en esa ventana los print que hagas. Tienes que buscar otro modo de validar estas cosas en django.

Por lo que comentas, llega a mostrate el html, y también a ejecutar el javascript, con lo que la funcion la estará ejecutando.

Echa un vistazo al modulo loggin https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/logging/